# Get result displayed in form / textfield

Tags: javascript, html

I have an ajax script which fetches results from a web-service and displays them in a div, however I would like them to be displayed in an input area / text field.

My main script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function get_CODES_Results() {
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<img src=\'loading.gif\' />";
      var url = document.location;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      else if (window.ActiveXObject) req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      req.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
      //req.open("GET", url, true);
      //req.send(null);
      req.open("POST",url,true);
      req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      req.send("codes="+document.getElementById("codes").value);
      function processRequest() {
         if (req.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = req.responseText;
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

And here the area where it is being displayed:

```
<p>
   <h3>Results:</h3>
   <div id="results"></div>
</p>
```

My question:

> How can I achieve that my result is displayed in an input/text-field?

Some advice would be highly appreciated - thank you, Patrick

Comment: Can you use req.responseText directly in an input/text-field? Or you need to extract value to be populated from req.responseText?

Comment: I would need the response / result to be displayed directly in the input area / textfield.

Comment: Have you considered using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make those requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
document.getElementById("results").value = req.responseText;
```

And then you results should be an input:

```
<input type="text" id="results" />
```

Answer (score 2):

this?

```
document.getElementById("results").value = req.responseText;

<input id="results" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose this is your text field:

```
<input type="text" id="whatever" value="" />
```

Simply set the response to its value:

```
document.getElementById('whatever').value = req.responseText;
```

Comment: Thank you coder - the solution seems to work fine.I was wondering if I can have my result appened to a default value? Basically I would like to use a default value (e.g. mystore.com) in my field and the result appended onto it. Basically: mystore.com/resultfromajaxscript

Comment: document.getElementById('whatever').value = 'mystore.com/' + req.responseText;

Comment: If the value is already set before then you can use `document.getElementById('whatever').value += req.responseText;` or else `document.getElementById('whatever').value = 'mystore.com/' + req.responseText;`